# Wann kann man Verben der Form [etwas]bekommen durch [etwas]kriegen ersetzen?

Tags: verb, slang

*Kriegen* sei die (oder eine) umgangssprachliche Version des Verbes *bekommen*, wurde mir mal gesagt. Ich hätte diese Behauptung hier sorgfältiger bestätigen lassen.

Soweit kenne ich nur eine kleine Liste von Verben der Form

> [Präfix]kriegen (z.B. hinkriegen, durchkriegen, mitkriegen,…).

Diejenigen, die ich kenne, sind durch die jeweilige Version

> [Präfix]bekommen

ersetzbar. Gibt es Ausnahmen?

Ist jedes Verb der Form `[Präfix]kriegen` Umgangssprache für die durch *bekommen* ersetzte Version?

Comment: Possibly [related answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/6397/5398). Indeed, they are almost perfect synonyms (except for register, with "kriegen" being more colloquial). I cannot think of an example where one could not be replaced by the other.

Comment: bekriegen != bekommen ;)

Comment: @FranzEbner, that would be "bebekommen", if you want to keep the analogy.

Comment: "Bekommen" kann mit der Bedeutung "wohl tun" verwendet werden ("etwas bekommt mir nicht"), "kriegen" jedoch nicht.

Comment: *sich einkriegen* ≠ *?sich einbekommmen*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most existing mismatches are already in the comments, so I’ve done something different: a quick search in the [DeReWo 320000g](http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/methoden/derewo.html) base forms corpus. 
Whatever dictionaries may say, some of the possible synonyms are in use, others are not.

The number in parenthesis is the word’s rank among the c. 320.000 lexemes present in the corpus. Sometimes they’re quite similar for both forms, sometimes one variant is clearly favored. 
(Perhaps I should have provided the word occurrence classes instead.)

If there was no search result for one of them, that doesn’t mean it wouldn’t be understood (or used) by native speakers. 
Where both variants exist, they’re usually synonymous, although certain semantic nuances may be associated with one but not the other, e.g. both parts of *rumkriegen* are marked slightly as colloquial, in a raised register one would rather expect *herumbekommen* (where the object could be a car around a corner or a short-time sexual interest).

- kriegen (2653 ⇒ 12) : bekommen (230 ⇒ 8)

### Occurences

Hits for both (which does not necessarily imply they’re synonymous):

- abkriegen (62.340) : abbekommen (19.446)
- ankriegen (309.552) : anbekommen (305.298)
- aufkriegen (185.917) : aufbekommen (134.187)
- draufkriegen (260.543) : draufbekommen (271.276)
- durchkriegen (142.009) : durchbekommen (102.124)
- fertigkriegen (281.465) : fertigbekommen (257.194)
- flottkriegen (215.966) : flottbekommen (239.525)
- freikriegen (180.729) : freibekommen (46.121)
- herauskriegen (86.215) : herausbekommen (26.892)
- hereinkriegen (290.325) : hereinbekommen (94.078)
- herkriegen (152.299) : herbekommen (87.077)
- herumkriegen (194.787) : herumbekommen (294.772)
- herunterkriegen (295.873) : herunterbekommen (244.494)
- hineinkriegen (281.606) : hineinbekommen (141.632)
- hinkriegen (21.042) : hinbekommen (21.171)
- hochkriegen (152.851) : hochbekommen (256.449)
- kleinkriegen (74.998) : kleinbekommen (318.285)
- loskriegen (217.764) : losbekommen (204.749)
- mitkriegen (32.720) : mitbekommen (8.875)
- rauskriegen (60.965) : rausbekommen (99.934)
- reinkriegen (104.425) : reinbekommen (118.210)
- spitzkriegen (226.431) : spitzbekommen (305.044)
- vollkriegen (133.973) : vollbekommen (222.889)
- wegkriegen (90.093) : wegbekommen (67.070)
- wiederkriegen (219.633) : wiederbekommen (53.757)
- zukriegen (235.339) : zubekommen (173.535)
- zurückkriegen (180.598) : zurückbekommen (19.712)
- zusammenkriegen (89.249) : zusammenbekommen (29.541)

Hits for *+kriegen* but not *+bekommen*:

- auskriegen (313.805) : ?ausbekommen
- bekriegen (42.100) : *bebekommen
- drankriegen (212.833) : dranbekommen
- einkriegen (134.806) : ?einbekommen
- fortkriegen (319.926) : ?fortbekommen
- hierherkriegen (321.758) : ?hierherbekommen
- kaputtkriegen (218.246) : ?kaputtbekommen
- klarkriegen (283.897) : ?klarbekommen
- rankriegen (295.113) : ?ranbekommen
- rüberkriegen (303.943) : ?rüberbekommen
- rumkriegen (112.784) : ?rumbekommen
- runterkriegen (215.159) : ?runterbekommen
- totkriegen (79.672) : ?totbekommen
- überkriegen (319.591) : ?überbekommen
- unterkriegen (28.385) : ?unterbekommen
- zerkriegen (304.249) : *zerbekommen
- Kinderkriegen (265.955) : Kinderbekommen

Hits for *+bekommen* but not *+kriegen*

- dazukriegen : dazubekommen (72.508)
- ?hinzukriegen : hinzubekommen (45.957)
- ?nachkriegen : nachbekommen (312.208)

Hits for neither, but listed at [verblisten.de](http://www.verblisten.de/listen/verben/endung/zusammengesetzt/infinitiv-%2abekommen/vollstaendig.html):

- ?sattkriegen : sattbekommen
- ?auseinanderkriegen : auseinanderbekommen

Answer (score -3):

Wenn es im Sinne von etwas erhalten ist, ja. In anderen Fällen nicht.