# Wieso sind auch von »kriegen« und »bekommen« abgeleitete Verben synonym?

Tags: etymology, synonym

Im Deutschen gibt es eine Parallele zwischen den Verben *kriegen* und *bekommen,* die meines Wissens einzigartig ist: Nicht nur sind die beiden synonym, sondern [auch viele abgeleiteten Verben](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/13513/2594) (wie *mitkriegen/mitbekommen)* oder Phrasen (wie *etwas auf die Reihe kriegen/etwas auf die Reihe bekommen),* obwohl sich diese häufig verselbständigt haben und ihre Bedeutung daher nicht mehr direkt aus den Komponenten ableitbar ist.

Im Gegensatz dazu sind andere Synonyme häufig nur auf die ursprünglichen Wörter beschränkt. Zum Beispiel sind zwar *kaufen* und *erwerben* synonym, aber es gibt keine Analogien zu *abkaufen, ankaufen, verkaufen* oder *Politiker kaufen* mit *erwerben.* Das gilt auch für andere Sprachen: Zum Beispiel sind im Englischen *to get* und *to obtain* weitestgehend synonym, es gibt aber keine Analogien zu *to beget, to forget* oder *to get lost* mit *obtain.*

**Woher kommt diese außergewöhnliche Parallelität?** Es geht mir vor allem darum, was *kriegen* und *bekommen* von anderen Synonympaaren abgrenzt.

Comment: So einzigartig ist das nicht: im Japanischen gibt es die beiden Verben *ageru* und *kureru*, die beide "geben" bedeuten, das eine vom Standpunkt des Gebers, das andere vom Standpunkt des Empfängers (ein Äquivalent zu "bekommen" gibt es auch, *morau*). Vom Sprachregister abgesehen hat für mich "kriegen" eher auch die Bedeutung eigener Aktivität, während "bekommen" auf die Aktivität eines anderen hinweist.

Answer (score 6):

Nur eine Theorie, aber ich vermute, dass es sich um Zufall/eine Sache der Wahrnehmung handelt. Einige Gedanken dazu:

- *sich einkriegen* vs. *sich *einbekommen* wäre ein Gegenbeispiel;
- *kriegen* und *bekommen* gehören m. E. in zwei verschiedene Register:
  *bekommen* ist Standardsprache, *kriegen* (in der Regel) eher Umgangssprache - allerdings werden beide häufig verwendet, ebenso wie
  die betreffenden Register;
- anders bei *kaufen* und *erwerben*:
  *kaufen* ist Standardsprache, *erwerben* deutlich gehoben. Entsprechend ungleich ist die Verwendungsfrequenz.

Man könnte nun zaghaft die These aufstellen, dass solche Kongruenzen eher bei Wörtern auftreten, die in den häufig verwendeten Registern Standard- und Umgangssprache verwendet werden, und eher nicht bei Wörtern, bei denen eins ins weniger häufige Register "gehobene Sprache" fällt. Überzeugt bin ich allerdings noch nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Die Beobachtung finde ich erstaunlich, es handelt sich jedoch nicht um reine Synonyme, also Wörter mit vollkommen austauschbaren Bedeutungen und Verwendungsmustern (falls es solche überhaupt gibt).

> kriegen

klingt nicht nur wie "Krieg", sondern hat damit direkt zu tun, denn es bedeutet grundsätzlich *sich etwas erstreiten, erkriegen, um etwas (erfolgreich) ringen*. Entsprechend trägt das Verb neben der Vorstellung vom In-Besitz-Nehmen auch die Vorstellung von einer aktiven, auch aggressiven Bemühung:

```
Warte nur, dich krieg ich noch!
```

Vielleicht liege ich damit falsch, aber das könnte auch der Grund sein, warum das Wort es nicht wirklich in die Hochsprache geschafft hat. Es hängt ihm der Geruch einer Anstrengung an, zu Ressourcen bzw. zum Ziel zu kommen, die gebildeten und gutsituierten Schichten eher fremd ist.

> bekommen

hingegen verbindet sich mit der Vorstellung eines Gewinns, der einem auch ohne Bemühung auf seinem Weg zuteil werden kann, im Sinn von "zu etwas kommen", "etwas erreichen", vielleicht nicht zufällig Verben der Bewegung.

Eine mögliche Erklärung für die Parallelität der Ableitungen von "kriegen" und "bekommen" könnte in der klaren Funktionalität dieser Vorsilben liegen, welche jeweils vergleichbare Bedeutungen für zwei Synonyme erzeugen, die in unterschiedlichen Sprech- und sozialen Situationen gebraucht werden.

Comment: Zum letzten Absatz: Das müsste dann aber auch für andere Verben funktionieren.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Für "werfen/schmeißen" funktioniert es in einigen Fällen, siehe unten, aber das hängt m.E. sehr vom Verhältnis der beiden Verben zueinander ab.

Comment: "Warte nur, dich krieg ich noch!" - ist das nicht nur eine Verkürzung von so was wie "Dich kriege ich noch zu fassen!", was sich genauso als "Dich bekomme ich noch zu fassen!" ausdrücken lässt? Ich sehe/"spüre" da eigentlich keinen Zusammenhang mit Streit oder Krieg, da "kriegen" umgangssprachlich ja auch genauso für vollkommen freiwillige Handlungen verwendet wird ("Was hast du zum Geburtstag gekriegt?"; "Ich habe es hingekriegt."; "Sobald ich das Buch ausgelesen habe, kriegst du es von mir."; "Ich möchte, dass du das Haus kriegst." (all diese Beispiele gehen genauso mit "bekommen")).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Die etymologische Verbindung zwischen "kriegen" und "Krieg" ist eindeutig, sowohl Kluge als auch Grimm und Pfeifer weisen darauf hin. In der umgangssprachlichen Verwendung hat sich das jedoch enorm auf einen "normalen" Gebrauch verbreitert, und die "aggressiven" Konnotationen von "kriegen" gibt es bei "bekommen" nicht.

Answer (score 2):

*Kriegen* ist ein Wort der Umgangssprache und wird in der geschriebenen Sprache meist als Stilfehler angesehen. *Bekommen* ist ein Wort der Literatursprache und kann in der Umgangssprache leicht affektiert klingen. Dasselbe gilt für Zusammensetzungen mit diesen Wörtern.

Vielen Kindern wird die Benutzung von *kriegen* aberzogen - was natürlich nur deshalb nötig ist, weil sie so verbreitet ist. (Woher sollten die Kinder das Wort sonst lernen?) Spätestens in der Schule lernen sie dann, dass sie nicht *kriegen* schreiben sollen, sondern *bekommen*. Anscheinend übersetzen wir ganz selbstverständlich zwischen Literatur- und Umgangssprache hin und her, indem wir (u.A.) diese beiden Wörter austauschen. Da es sich nur um zwei Register derselben Sprache handelt, funktioniert diese Übersetzung auch in Zusammensetzungen größtenteils rein mechanisch. (Wir sprechen schriftsprachlich beeinflusste Umgangssprache und schreiben umgangssprachlich beeinflusste Schriftsprache.)

Zu der [früheren Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13513) hat Crissov eine Reihe von Beispielen gegeben, in denen die mechanische Übersetzung von der Umgangssprache in die Literatursprache nicht funktioniert. Z.T. sind das Verben, in denen *kriegen* in seinem ursprünglichen Sinn verwendet wird und daher auch in der Literatursprache korrekt ist (*bekriegen, zerkriegen*). Z.T. sind es unrettbar umgangssprachliche Wörter, die selbst nach der Übersetzung noch als unpassend empfunden werden (*sich auskriegen, hierherkriegen, kaputtkriegen*). Z.T. enthalten diese Wörter noch eine weitere Komponente, die man ebenfalls übersetzen muss (*runterkriegen* wird zu *herunterbekommen*, nicht *runterbekommen*).

Comment: Das ist ja alles schön und gut, aber wieso funktioniert es dann für andere umgangssprachliche Verben nicht? Zum Beispiel *werfen – schmeißen – verwerfen – X* oder *sehen – gucken – übersehen – X.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Bei werfen und schmeißen funktioniert das zumindest mit den Vorsilben be-, ein- bzw. rein-, hin-, um-, ver- und weg-.

Comment: *Schmeißen* wird verglichen mit *kriegen* als noch ordinärer empfunden, und im Gegensatz zu *bekommen* ist *werfen* ein ganz normales umgangssprachliches Wort. Hier liegt die Grenze also nicht zwischen Umgangssprache und Schriftsprache, sondern innerhalb der Umgangssprache. *Sehen* und *gucken* sind - außer vielleicht in ein paar Dialekten - genauso wenig äquivalent wie *see* und *look* im Englischen. Und auch hier gilt, dass *sehen* im Gegensatz zu *bekommen* auch in der Umgangssprache ein ganz normales, unauffälliges Verb ist.